# Custom layout for input of data in android

Tags: android, xml

### I am trying to achieve the things shown in figure

---

**rounded_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

**search_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#C0C0C0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="5dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Breakfast" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lunch" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dinner" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Search" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

### I have an output like below::

[image]

---

### How to modify my xml so that i could achieve like below::

[image]

**I am trying to get the exact same layout as above**

- I am also trying to use a `edittext` for date as shown in the `second
  pic` wather than i have achieved
- also i am trying to get all the things in box rows as displayed as
  above

***Any ideas ?***

**Hope i am clear !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="City"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="type"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="breakfast"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="lunch"
         android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="dinner"
         android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Search"/>
```

Comment: Thanks ! .....Everything fits .... but i want to ask one thing ..... can u explain the logic involved in date you have used ..... you have taken 3 edit text to make three boxes .... suppose i want to reference date using like button.getString() to extract value of button ..... how should i reference date widget .... since its like 3 boxes ..... i need to use something like ..... edittextofdate.getstring() .... but how to implement here ? .. any suggestions ?

Comment: as i dnt knw anything about your project but according to me u should use date picker for date picking..

Comment: Hey the reason for my ambiguity was ..... there are three seperate edittext views .... so instead of one view for whole text .... so .. But ... hey thanks for answer :)